# Reuse the same CERT_CONTEXT in multi-threaded CryptSignMessage calls

Tags: winapi, cryptography, cryptoapi

I want to implement some sort of "batch signing" scenario using [`CryptSignMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptsignmessage).

Each call to `CryptSignMessage` must use the same certificate. I plan to obtain `CERT_CONTEXT` once from store, and then reuse it in parallel `CryptSignMessage` calls.

Assuming, that each call (thread) will operate its own instance of `CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA` and data to be signed, but the same pointer to `CERT_CONTEXT`, will this be correct usage?

In other words, is such `CryptSignMessage` usage thread-safe?

Comment: the *pSigningCert* used as read only (by fact used for get private key container). this can be used my multiple threads at once. such CryptSignMessage usage is thread-safe

Comment: Yeah, it seems to use only (thread-) local parameters outside of the configuration parameters in the `CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA` structure. As all the buffering etc. is performed locally in the function, it should be safe to operate. There is also the `GetLastError` function but that reads "Retrieves the **calling thread's** last-error code value. The last-error code is maintained on a per-thread basis. Multiple threads do not overwrite each other's last-error code." so clearly this is made with multi-threading in mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you turn comments into answers?

Comment: @maa You are reading a lot into `GetLastError` that's not there. The fact that an API sets the calling thread's last error code is no indication that the API were indeed designed with multi-threading in mind.

Comment: @IInspectable It is certainly an **indication**, which is backed up by the comment of RbMm and knowledge that the params are immutable. It's certainly not **proof**, but you'll have to look to Microsoft for that; if it was made clear in the class / method descriptions we would not have to answer it here.

Comment: @maa It's not an indication, not even one bit. The last error code being isolated per thread is a concession to the fact that Windows had multi-threading support built into the kernel from day 1 (ignoring 16-bit Windows). That's unlike, say, Linux, that had multi-threading support bolted on, as an afterthought. With a broken `errno`, that only got fixed decades later with C11. Now if you look up the documentation for `errno`, does that make **any** indication about thread compatibility for any given function that sets it?

Comment: really `GetLastError ` not indication here. many win32 api instead return error code direct, save it in thread environment block (TEB). but this nothing say about are api "thread-safe". however in case `CryptSignMessage` all `CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA` (with internal pointers ) is readonly by design. api only read data from it but nothing modify here. multiple thread at once can use same data until all it only read it. only in case some threads can modify this data - already need syncronization. but here no modify